# xargs works in command line but not in Bash script?

Tags: shell-script, iptables, xargs

Ok, so I am new to linux and also bash script.

I am trying to use bash script to manipulate iptables.  I need to delete all entries in the iptables where the source ip matches.  I found a code which was able to do so:

```
iptables -S FORWARD | grep 10.7.0.6 | cut -d " " -f 2- |xargs -rL1 iptables -D
```

Where this will delete all the iptables entries with source IP of 10.7.0.6

This command execute great in the command line (terminal), but when I use this in the Bash script, why it gives me this error?  (see below)

```
"xargs: iptables: No such file or directory"
```

I am running under Ubuntu 22.04.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How/where is the `iptables` command? You can find out with `type -a iptables`. Also, what is your `PATH` (use `echo "$PATH"` to find out).

Comment: Gordon, you are live saver!  THANK YOU VERY MUCH!  That worked.  So I guess xargs is looking for the file of the "iptables"?  I changed my commnad (in bash) to xargs lrL1 /usr/sbin/iptables -D and it worked! :)